# What does toascii do?

Tags: c, ascii

What does the function `toascii()` do?

Is there any practical use for it?

Note: This is not about the Windows function `ToAscii`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the POSIX `toascii`, it says what it does right in the `man` page.

> toascii() converts c to a 7-bit unsigned char value that fits into the ASCII character set, by clearing the high-order bits.

If you need to ensure a value only uses the lowest seven bits, then you have a use for it, but you're probably more likely to bitwise-AND the value with `0x7F`.

Comment: Ah. It only keeps the lowest seven bits. That makes sense.

Comment: As a side note, I should mention that as of POSIX 2008, `toascii` is considered an obsolete function.

Answer (score 0):

It converts and `int` sized parameter (`c`) to a 7-bit ascii value by clearing higher order bits.  Effectively it returns `c & 0x7f`.